# compatiblity of netbeans with 7 home basic 64 bits

Tags: netbeans-6.9

is netbeans compatible with windows7 home basic 64 bits?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is compatible with Windows7 64bits (running it myself). You can either use a 64bit VM or a 32bit VM whatever you prefer.